# Can i use wild card with browserify require?

Tags: javascript, browserify

Currently for loading a module in a folder, i need to explicitly call each file:

```
require('path/to/file/someFile.js')
```

Is there a way to require all modules in a folder using a wild card? something like:

```
require('path/to/file/*.js')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a browserify transform such as [bulkify](http://github.com/substack/bulkify):

```
var bulk = require('bulk-require');
var whatever = bulk(__dirname, [ '*.js' ]);
```